# Create buttons in the editor

Tags: unity, c#, editors

So I've seen people  do stuff like

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class [ScriptName] : Editor
{
   // A bunch of code that I can't understand.
}
```

but what exactly do they do to make buttons on their script?

Comment: This is usually done by overriding [OnInspectorGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.OnInspectorGUI.html) and including a call to [GUI.Button](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html), or the newer method with UIElements by overriding [CreateInspectorGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.CreateInspectorGUI.html) and creating a [Button](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Button.html) element. If you can explain what specific code you need help with, we can target answers to help with the specific aspect you're confused about.

Comment: However, if you don't understand any of it, then you might be a bit early in your learning journey yet for this particular task, and you may want to consider following some beginner tutorials to get a solid grasp of the language and the conventions for how it's used in Unity before returning to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity provides an ability to override the `OnInspectorGUI` function which is called when drawing an inspector window for a specific script.

The way it works is you can just create a new class derived from Editor class and tell the unity to create our custom inspector windows for your specific script.

And then in your `OnInspectorGUI` you can ask unity to draw all sorts of controls including buttons, color dialogs, sliders, etc!

**Now to make a simple button with the traditional "Hello World" text, follow this code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool doesntMatter;
}


[CustomEditor(typeof(MyScript))]
public class MyScriptEditor : Editor
{
    void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        var myScript = target as MyScript;
        myScript.doesntMatter= EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Hello World"); //Returns true when user clicks
    }
}
```

---

---

**Now if you've got a good grasp, here's something that you might actually need when creating custom inspector windows:**

*When the user toggles a checkmark, more variables wqill be shown to the user.*

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class MyScript2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool show = false;
    public int num1;
    public float num2;
    public bool anotherToggle = false;
    public GameObject go;
}


[CustomEditor(typeof(MyScript2))]
public class MyScript2Editor : Editor
{
    void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        var myScript2 = target as MyScript2;

        myScript2.show = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Show Hidden Values");
        myScript2.anotherToggle = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Show Another Hidden Value");

        if(myScript2.show)
            myScript2.num1 = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Enter a number:", myScript2.num1);
            myScript2.num2 = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Choose float between 1 to 10:", myScript2.num2, 0, 10f);
            if(myScript2.anotherToggle)
                myScript2.go = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Very hidden gameObject:", go, typeof(GameObject));
    }
}
```

---

---

---

Hope this helped you create your first inspector windows :)

Comment: This is actually very simillar to a [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/brackeys) video I watched about custom inspectors

Comment: cannot convert string to boolean for you first example, on this line `myScript.doesntMatter= EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Hello World"); //Returns true when user clicks`

Answer (score 1):

A solution I often use is creating "pseudo-buttons" using bools and Unity's OnValidate() method

```
    void ExampleMethod()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello World!");
    }

    public bool pseudoButton = false;
    void OnValidate()
    {
        if (pseudoButton)
        {
            ExampleMethod();

            pseudoButton = false;
        }
    }
```

It's a bit of a hacky, but its useful for quick debugging, and to not waste time with creating a new custom